# Error in connection establishment of socket no-credentials-available

Tags: vue.js, sockets

I am receiving below error on socket test from JavaScript.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://no-credentials-available/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Comment: For some reason you are trying to connect to a host named no-credentials-available which obviously doesn't exist. Can you show your code where you are creating the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to import credentials as explained in [AWS IoT SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#websocket-configuration) git repo